# Python - Pandas - groupby and "agg" - set aggregate to nan when group contains a nan

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, nan

I have the following example:

```
index_ = pd.date_range('2001-01-01', '2010-12-31', freq = 'MS')
df_ = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(index_), 4), columns=list('ABCD'),  index = index_ )
df_.loc['2009-01-01','A'] = np.nan
df_.loc['2007-08-01','B'] = np.nan
df_.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('A')).agg({'A': np.sum, 'B': np.mean})
```

I like to have that column 'B' is `NaN` in 2007 and column 'A' is `NaN` in 2009. How can this be achieved? I tried the `np.sum` function because in numpy arrays it returns `NaN` when the array contains a nan value. Can this be translated to the "agg" command which I would like to use here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use parameter `skipna=False` in [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sum.html) and [`mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mean.html):

```
np.random.seed(100)
index_ = pd.date_range('2001-01-01', '2010-12-31', freq = 'MS')
df_ = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(index_), 4), columns=list('ABCD'),  index = index_ )
df_.loc['2009-01-01','A'] = np.nan
df_.loc['2007-08-01','B'] = np.nan
df = df_.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('A')).agg({'A': lambda x: x.sum(skipna=False), 
                                           'B': lambda x: x.mean(skipna=False)})
print (df)
                   B         A
2001-12-31  0.184784  0.593025
2002-12-31 -0.251913 -1.720891
2003-12-31 -0.085896 -3.060836
2004-12-31 -0.327153  6.561670
2005-12-31  0.214115  3.400988
2006-12-31  0.270536  2.972164
2007-12-31       NaN  4.175623
2008-12-31  0.429060 -2.917714
2009-12-31  0.222544       NaN
2010-12-31 -0.339483  2.021474
```